# Web images from cgm

Tags: graphics, web, metafile

I am trying to use computer graphics metafile (cgm) in my web pages. I am using PHP and Javascript. So I am trying to find the structure of the file to be able to read it and draw its images. I am also searching for an open source software that can be embedded in web pages, not a stand alone application. I have read all the papers on Webcgm, but I couldn't find what I need. If anyone has suggestions or advice on how to implement cgm that will be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a Java applet an option for you? E.g. http://www.bdaum.de/howto.htm describes how to use one. See http://www.coderanch.com/t/259381/Applets/java/display-CGM-images-iingn-web for more discussion.

As an alternative, you could convert your CGM files to SVG or PDF on the server. You could do that either in advance, or on-the-fly, depending on your requirements. E.g. http://www.cgmlarson.com/convert_CGM_to_PDF_aerospace.html has a server license. (I don't know anything about the suitability or price of the product.)

Comment: Thanks @LarsH. Those all require purchase of the license. Your advice confirms my research.

Comment: @user2433537: Glad to help, but please don't assume my answer is exhaustive. I'm not knowledgeable about CGM on the web; I just did some googling.

Comment: I know. It is just a topic that is not very well supported.